# (Adjacency) Matrix Multiplication VS Graph Homomorphism

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

Recently I've been looking at graph homomorphisms. Given adjacency matrices A(G) and A(H) and a graph homomorphism from G to H, is there any way to express this in terms of the adjacency matrices A(G) and A(H)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general there is no way to relate the existence of a homomorphisms to properties of the adjacency matrices of the graphs. Admittedly it is possible to decide if a graph is bipartite, but if you are asking if there is a homomorphism between two arbitrary graphs, then the adjacency matrix does not help.

Comment: OK, thanks Chris.And none of the other matrices either (Laplacian etc.), I take it...

Comment: @John Smith: the other matrices do not help - if the graph is regular they all give the same information.